# Where are the hashing utils in nodejs?

Tags: anchor, web3.js, data, node.js, hashing

I'm looking in both @solana/web3.js and @project-serum/anchor and don't see any hashing utils. What should one use to pack and hash data in nodejs? I suppose I could use ethereum/web3.js, but pulling in an Ethereum dependency for this seems odd.

Thanks

Comment: If you're referring to serialization, generally the standard is borsh, which ironically is maintained by Near (https://github.com/near/borsh-js). If you're referring to hashing, I would just use the standard crypto library provided by nodejs (https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) which provides access to most hash algorithms you might use.

Comment: @ElliotSolskjaer the borsh-js library is EXACTLY what I needed. Considering BorshSerialize is how data is packed in Rust, this companion nodejs library saved me. Give an official answer, and I'll approve it. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :). Just added an official answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referring to serialization, generally the standard for Solana & Rust is Borsh, which you can use in javascript with [borsh-js](https://github.com/near/borsh-js).

If you're referring to hashing, I would just use the [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) library provided by nodejs which provides access to most hash algorithms you might use.